# Mi estilo no se aplica automáticaente

Tags: html, css, style

**Hola**

Yo estoy intentando agregar una hoja de estilos a mi página web y estoy usando la siguiente etiqueta: `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo 'style.css' ?>" />`, pero estos estilos no se aplican a la página.

Al inspenccionar el código (Herramienta de desarrollo de chrome) y mirar los archivos que han sido cargados, el archivo se encuentra ahí, lo abro, y al modificarlo (por ejemplo al poner un espacio al final del archivo) los estilos se aplican automáticamente.

No entiendo por qué si el archivo se carga y al editarlo en el inspector de código se aplican los archivos, por qué al car gar la página ¿no se aplican?

**Nota**
el archivo no tiene ningún error

Comment: ¿Lo estás usando en un archivo HTML o PHP?

Comment: Los cambios realizados a los archivos cargados en el Inspector de Chrome (pestaña de Sources) no se guardan en el sistema. Hay una símbolo amarillo de alerta que aparece encima de la pestaña del archivo cuando lo intentas guardar.

Comment: Independientemente de si carga o no carga, no entiendo porque haces un echo de ese texto en lugar de quitar el PHP y ponerlo directamente, total, no es ninguna variable que se resuelva, es simple texto y no hace falta el PHP para incluirlo, lo haces directamente y ya.

Comment: No hago un echo, lo que hago es un include.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que para que el proyecto se pueda escalar y modifiicar con más facilidad va a estar dividido en módulos los cuales tendrán su propio estilo y estrucrura y coportamiento, pero quiero cargar todos los entilos en un mismo archivo para que el vanegador no tenga que descargar el archivo de cada módulo

Comment: Vale, entiendo, pero ojo con eso, bueno, con todos los CSS y de hecho con todos los archivos estaticos, porque si haces muchos cambios o pocos, pero de forma constante, es probable que algunos navegadores los tengan guardados en cache y no se actualicen al momento, sino al cabo de dias.

Comment: Por cierto, que no sea ese el problema, es decir, que antes, por lo que sea, cargastes ese archivo sin apenas estilos en tu navegador, y se guardó en cache, y ahora no estés bajandolo de nuevo, sino que lo recupera del cache,y como apenas tiene estilos o ninguno, pues no te funciona.  Cuando tengas la página abierta y tengas ese problema, pulsa la tecla Shift del teclado, y mientras la mantienes pulsada, dale con el raton al botón de refrescar la página que aparece arriba al lado de la barra de la URL. Con ese truco estas impidiendo que lo lea del cache y lo vaya a buscar de nuevo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

luego de mucho navegar pude encontrar la respuesta.

Lo que sucedía era que el navegador esperaba un encabezado con `document-type: text/css` (o sea que 3speraba un documento css), pero el servidor al procesar con PHP la respuesta, enviaba un documento con texto html `document-type: text/html`, lo cual causaba que no leyera los 3stilos al momento de solicitarlos. Solo tube que colocar una línea de código en el servidor al momento de procesar el css y es el siguiente:

```
header('document-type: text/css');
```

Lo cual cambia este valor de la cabecera y evita ese conflicto,

Extra: lo que se va a devolver es un archivo .js debes colocar:

```
header('document-type: text/css');
```

Comment: En el primer header tal vez le falte una comilla, o tal vez lo veo mal :)